# "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)-while using sqlcipher in ios

Tags: ios, encrypted-core-data-sql

I am a newbie in ios development and encrypting core data's sqlite file first time.I have installed all the pods ,checked dependencies but still getting "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" again and again,after trying several times.Kindly help me to understand this error and solve it.Anyhelp would be appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Comment: try cltr+skift + k to clean the project and press alt Product-> Clean Build folder.

Comment: @Priyal ..done..but no result,still getting same error.

Comment: The linker can't find `libEncryptedCoreData.a`. Check your linker search paths in the build settings.